# Get inverse of a matrix step-by-step

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, inverse

How can I get the inverse of a matrix step by step?

**An example:** Given the matrix `{{8, 2}, {3, 2}}´, the result is {{$\frac{1}{5}$, -$\frac{1}{5}$}, {-$\frac{3}{10}$, $\frac{4}{5}$}}. But how can I get it step by step?

I have tried to use some commands that I have found on the internet but they did not work.

Comment: Step-by-step solutions are not a feature of Mathematica, but they do seem to be a feature of Wolfram Alpha Pro: http://www.wolframalpha.com/pro/step-by-step-math-solver.html I'm not sure if matrix inverse is included in this.

Comment: If by "step" you mean an elementary row operation, I think you would have to write your own program (or look for one on the web).  I believe the *Mathematica* steps are basically to send the matrix to the linear algebra library and wait for the result.  See [`tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html).

Comment: As @Michael E2 suggests, it's a very good exercise for *Mathematica* novices to write little functions that implement the 3 elementary row operations: scaling a matrix row, adding one matrix row to another, and interchanging two matrix rows. Then write a longer function that calls those functions in order to reduce a matrix to a reduced row echelon form. If the entries are going to be numeric, you'll want a function to round to 0 exactly entries that are sufficiently small. For more practical results, write and call a function that does partial pivoting.

Comment: I forgot to mention another auxiliary function to define on the way to constructing a program to find matrix inverses: one that adjoins to a given (square) matrix an identity matrix of the same shape. Moreover, you can make the process even fancier - and more realistic - by using *scaled* partial pivoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single method to get the inverse of a matrix, but if you only want to know how to get the inverse for arbitrary values of the matrix, ask MMA to solve it symbolically and use the resulting expression!

```
mat = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
Inverse@mat
(* {{d/(-b c + a d), -(b/(-b c + a d))}, {-(c/(-b c + a d)), a/(-b c + a d)}} *)
```

Comment: I don't think that's the sort of "step-by-step" method the original question had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Using some intermediate steps.

```
m = {{8, 2}, {3, 2}};
Quiet@Needs["Combinatorica`"]
adjoint = Transpose[Array[Cofactor[m, {#1, #2}] &, Dimensions[m]]];
determinant = Det[m];
inverse = adjoint/determinant
```

Comment: For any but the smallest order matrices, using the cofactor method is a computationally inefficient way to find matrix inverses.

Comment: Thanks, I might add another example using `LinearSolve` later.

Comment: But `LinearSolve` doesn't show the process step-by-step, as the original question specified.